# Состояние отрешённости, оцепенения, термин

Tags: терминология

Вот, собственно, хотел поинтересоваться: бывают моменты, когда узнаешь неприятную, ошеломляющую новость (либо попросту нервный срыв, либо психологическая нагрузка), наступает шок, после этого находишься в некоем отрешении, прострации (не подходит как ёмкое понятие, ибо подразумевает состояние подавленности и некой апатичности), и "уходишь в себя" (слышишь, что тебе говорят, но мысли реют где-то в сознании, всё проходит "мимо ушей"). Как это состояние называется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое слово **"дистресс"**. Чрезмерный стресс, с которым человеку трудно справиться. Что-то выходящее за рамки обычного для данного человека.

Видели на старых магнитофонах *индикаторы уровня записи*? Такие стрелочки, которые качаются туда-сюда при изменении громкости, и надо, чтобы они в красную зону шкалы не заходили. Если вдруг на входе магнитофона при записи звука ― чрезмерный уровень, то эти лёгкие, чувствительные стрелочки упираются в самый край шкалы и совсем перестают двигаться, не реагируют. Всё, уровень зашкалил.

Так и человеческие "контрольно-измерительные приборы" могут зашкалить, выйти за свой обычный диапазон и перестать воспринимать окружающее с обычной чувствительностью и остротой.

Вот по этой ссылке в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81#.D0.92.D0.B8.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.81.D0.B0) есть немного про дистресс.

.

Если попробовать подобрать всё же **русское** слово, то по-старинному это могли назвать **уныние**. Что традиционно считается очень нехорошим состоянием для души, которого нужно избегать. Ещё есть слово **подавленность**.

.

Вернусь к заимствованным словам. Слово **меланхолия** звучит, как мне кажется, тоже немного по-старому. *Меланхолия* дословно значит *"чёрная желчь"* ― в старину считали, что грустное, подавленное состояние происходит от *разлития желчи* внутри человека. Тоже считалось своего рода душевным нездоровьем.

Есть ещё слово **апатия**. Здесь я процитирую одну статью:

*Состояние бесчувственности, эмоциональной пассивности, бездеятельности, отсутствие влечений и желаний, которое развивается у подавленного человека, имеет свое название: апатия. Слово «апатия» происходит от греческого «apatheia» — бесстрастность.*

Вот [здесь](http://imho.net.ua/2014/06/16/apatiya.html), если угодно, можно почитать об апатии подробнее. Что это такое и от чего бывает. Там, по ссылке, уж извините, немного о политике вначале, но умеренно, а так ― то по моему скромному мнению ― познавательно. И чтобы понять суть, не обязательно разделять взгляды автора.

Comment: Судя по всему дистресс'ом и будет называться, благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

[Ступор](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80/%D0%91%D0%A1%D0%AD/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80/)?

Comment: Как вариант, но это уже из разряда медицины (подразумевая заболевание), а не психологии либо схожего.

Comment: Впасть в  ступор  вполне  бытовое  выражение.

Answer (score 2):

Прострация и называется. Чем не устраивает? Но это не термин.

**ПРОСТРАЦИЯ**, -и; ж. [лат. prostratio] *Книжн*.
Угнетённое, подавленное состояние, сопровождающееся полным упадком сил, безразличным отношением к окружающему. *Впасть в прострацию. Находиться в прострации. Найти кого-л. в полной прострации.*

Comment: Да, я уже видел эту статью на Вики, но речь идёт о некоем полутрансовом состоянии, с диссоциацией сознания (надеюсь понятно сформулировал).

Comment: Вики копирует из толковых словарей, в частности, вот это — из Большого толкового словаря Кузнецова.

Тогда вам, скорее всего, в медицинские справочники. Не придумал общелитературный язык названия такому хитрому состоянию.)))

Answer (score 0):

Это называется состоянием диссоциации еще. 
у меня тоже похожее состояние было и есть до сих пор. После тяжелых событий в моей жизни. Только вот как выйти из него - я не представляю.

Comment: Из любого стресса выходят без особого усилия. Уныние же, или теплохладность, побеждается заботой о другом, помощью любому, кто не откажется её принять.